# How to use redirect with multiple parameters in Django views?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to redirect to a function from another function in views.
But I am getting following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /sigma/status1/
Reverse for 'testview' with keyword arguments '{'amount': 1.000, 'stat':'Approved', 'ref': '10917'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['sigma\\/status2/(?P<amount>\\d+)/(?P<stat>[a-z][A-Z]+)/(?P<ref>\\d+)/$']
```

Below is corresponding part of my views.py

```
return redirect(reverse('testview',kwargs={'amount':1.000,'stat':'Approved','ref':str(res['ref'])}))


def payment_status2(request,amount,stat,ref):
  return render(request, 'confirm1.html')
```

Below is corresponding part of my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url('status1/', views.payment_status1),
  url(r'^status2/(?P<amount>\d+)/(?P<stat>[a-z][A-Z]+)/(?P<ref>\d+)/$', views.payment_status2,name="testview"),
  ]
```

Comment: I have edited the question now.Its ref only

Comment: Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stat` regex is incorrect:

```
?P<stat>[a-z][A-Z]+
```

This indicates that the argument should start with a lowercase letter and then followed by one or more uppercase letters (such as `aPPROVED`). You should change it to:

```
?P<stat>[a-zA-Z]+
```

or

```
?P<stat>\w+
```